# How to return value/message from one script to another script using functions in shell script?

Tags: shell

I need to call one shell script then it will call another shell script in this the actual logic implemented.

For example two scripts `first.sh` and `second.sh`

when I call the `first.sh` it will execute the `second.sh`

In `second.sh` code is defined to login  with ftp credentials.  I wanted to send/return back the status message whether login success/failure to `first.sh` using functions.

I have no idea about shell script can anyone please suggest me code snippet for above scenario?

Comment: Look at the `source` command (you can either use `source file2` or `. file2`)

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to do this is to make `second.sh` return a zero/nonzero exit status (with `exit 0` for OK and `exit 1` for FAILURE) and then test the exit status in `first.sh`:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 #   first.sh

 ...
 if second.sh; then
     printf '%s\n' "Login went swimmingly"
 else
     printf '%s\n' "Uh-oh, somehow login failed"
 fi
```

Along with

```
 #!/bin/sh
 #    second.sh

 ...
 if login using ftp worked; then
    exit 0
 else
    exit 1
 fi
```